# Vertical spacing issue on box

Tags: spacing, boxes

I'm trying to get the `resheading` box to be shorter in vertical space. Right now it appears that I have about 2 cm vertical space on the top and bottom of the text. How can I fix this?

Everything I think to be relevant:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.1in}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{10.5in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25in}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.85}  % Background color of title bars

\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{
  \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \begin{shaded}
        \textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}
    \end{shaded}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the features provided by the [mdframed](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.85}  % Background color

\newmdenv[backgroundcolor=shadecolor,topline=false,rightline=false,bottomline=false,
leftline=false]{infobox}


\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{%
    \begin{infobox}
        \noindent\sffamily\bfseries\large #1
    \end{infobox}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\resheading{\lipsum[1]}\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `aboveskip=<value>`, `belowskip=<value>`, and/or the other options, you can highly (and easily) customize your shaded environment.

Comment: I must insert a font key to the package ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This ended up doing the trick:

```
\begin{shaded}
    \vspace{-0.1in} % this line
    \textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}
    \vspace{-0.1in} % and this line
\end{shaded}
```

I didn't realize that `\vspace` is position sensitive.